# How to rename a Stored JavaScript in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rename, bson, database

Consider, I have a following Stored JavaScript in MongoDB

```
{_id: "sum",
 value: function (x, y) { return x + y; }}
```

It is been created by following command in MongoDB shell

```
db.system.js.save({_id: "sum",
value: function (x, y) { return x + y; }});
```

It can be run like:

```
db.eval("return sum(3, 5);");
8.0
```

Question: I want to change the name of my Stored JavaScript `sum` to `GetAddResult`. How can I do this without creating new Stored JavaScript?

---

Update:
I tried the following command to rename it.

```
db.system.js.update({'_id':'sum'}, {'$set':{'_id':'GetAddResult'}});
Mod on _id not allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the _id field of a mongodb document. Its an immutable object and hence you cannot alter the [Object Id](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) after creation of a document.

But you can try adding a new document with the preffered `_id` you would like to have.